# Value can not be null when retrieving token key .net 7 jwt

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-7.0

I am trying to implement JWT and I get a null exceptions error.

```
var testing = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                            .UTF8.GetBytes(config["TokenKey"]));
```

error message

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentNullException
> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Value cannot be null.'
> at System.ArgumentNullException.Throw(String paramName)
> at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
> at Vitrad.API.Extensions.IdentityServiceExtensions.AddIdentityServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) in D:\Documents\software\software.API\Extensions\IdentityServiceExtensions.cs:line 22
> at Program.d__0.MoveNext() in D:\Documents\software\software.API\Program.cs:line 31

appsettings.json

```
"AppSettings": {
    "TokenKey": "hereismytoken"
  },
```

Where it gets config

program.cs

```
internal class Program
{
 private static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
    builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);


    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => 
    {
        opt.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
               new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));
    });





    var app = builder.Build();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowCredentials()
        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://register.localhost:5000"));

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.MapControllers();
    app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");


    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
        await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
        
        Seed.SeedRoles(context, roleManager);
        Seed.SeedUsers(context, userManager);
        Seed.SeedClientPreference(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
    }



    app.Run();



    
}
```

IdentityServiceExtensions

```
public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
{
    
     public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration config)
    {

        var configValueTest = config; // does return some value
        var tokenReturnTest = config["AppSettings"];   // returns null
        var tokenReturntest2 = config["AppSettings:TokenKey"];   // returns null

        services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        })
            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();  

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                        .UTF8.GetBytes(config["AppSettings:TokenKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context => 
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && 
                            path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(opt => 
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            opt.AddPolicy("ModeratePhotoRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Moderator"));
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a simple typo, try `config["AppSettings:TokenKey"]`

Comment: Just tried it as var testing = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                            .UTF8.GetBytes(config["AppSettings:TokenKey"])); but still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to be sure, what is `config`, how do you get it and how is it set up?

Comment: Pull out `config["TokenKey"]` and `config["AppSettings:TokenKey"]` and save it to it's own variable first (`var value = config[...];`). What value does the variable have?

Comment: I did it for both and both come up as null.

Comment: Follow Guru's comment - something is wrong with how you're setting up your configuration. It has nothing to do with the SymmetricSecurityKey code.

Comment: it's in a class called IdentityServiceExtensions.cs. 
This gets the config from         builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);
in program.cs

Comment: I've just edited my question with the programs.cs and the IdentityServiceExtensions.cs.

Comment: Can you please add the whole settings file? Check also - maybe you are overriding the variable in the environment depended file or environment variables.

Comment: I have added the full code for program.cs, appsettings.json and IdentityServiceExtensions.cs

Comment: @GolfBravo `"AppSettings": {
    "TokenKey": "hereismytoken"
  },` is not a valid json.

Comment: It's not showing any errors and it's the same JSON that was used in .net 5 which worked.